# How do I remove all remnants of Subversion from a Visual Studio Solution

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I have just set up a new Subversion VisualSVN Server and am in the process of committing all of my projects to the various repositories. I am having an issue with some old code created by my predecessor (who used his own Subversion server, hosted at his house).

Basically it won't let me commit this project to my new server. If I just delete all of the '.svn' will this do the trick or is there more to it?

Thanks

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting all the .svn directories is sufficient enough.